# Geoserver Caching does not save tiles

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I want to cache a layer from Geoserver. I use Geoserver 2.5.1 on Ubuntu 13.10.

- In the `web.xml` file under `tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF` I added the following part:

   `<context-param>
          <param-name>GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR</param-name>
          <param-value>/opt/gwc</param-value>
   </context-param>`
- I enabled `Enable direct integration with GeoServer WMS` under
  Caching defaults.
- I use the sample data `tiger:giant_polygon` where `Create a cached layer for this layer` is enabled

After opening the tile preview with `EPSG:4326 /jpeg` for the layer, the folder where my tiles are supposed to be saved is still empty. Also the `DISK USED` colum shows `N/A`.
[image]

What is missing?

Comment: Have you given ownership of /home/uli/Downloads/tiles to Tomcat7?

Comment: also, check you Tomcat7 Logs [as per here](http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.5.1/troubleshooting/index.html)

Comment: Ok, you changed the directory, have you given tomcat7 ownership of /opt/gwc

Comment: If I try to change the ownership to Tomcat7 I get: `chown: invalid user: ‘Tomcat7’`

Comment: Also in the Geoserver Beginner's Guide book the owner of the folder is root. Are you sure the ownership needs to change?

Comment: I had to on my installation .. sorry, try tomcat7, case matters, my typo .. double check what user is running your Tomcat, it obviously needs write permissions to write to your cache directory ..

Comment: Please mark as correct answer by checking the Tick

Comment: You can edit your original post to include additional information/questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat and Geoserver need write permissions. You need to give tomcat7 ownership of /opt/gwc

Comment: The tiles are now saved inside /opt/gwc. Though the column `Disk Used` still shows `N/A`. What is the reason for that?

Comment: You need to ask a new question on that issue .. but possible you do not have enough tiles in there yet .. I have never paid much attention to that, I look at the directories to see how the caching is populating ..

Comment: you have to turn quota on for the disk used to update